# Fix 'Script invocation error' in Flutter iOS deploy

Tags: flutter

We've develop recently a new Flutter project. We have uploaded it to Google Play successfully but when we try to deploy it to the Apple App Store (after following the [official doc steps](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios)) we encounter the following error message while doing the XCode archive step:

> Shell Script invocation error:
>   - /bin/sh: /packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh: No such file or directory

I have reviewed within my Runner target/Build Phases/run script that the script is pointing to $FLUTTER_ROOT/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh in which $FLUTTER_ROOT is my flutter folder, so the xcode_backend.sh file exists.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried re-running flutter build ios?